# Сочетаемость союзов, предлогов и частиц

Tags: синтаксис, выбор-слов

Могут ли в речи следовать друг за другом:

1) предлог и союз;
2) союз и частица?

Именно в таком порядке и именно следовать — без всяких там кавычек, тире, запятых и проч., и проч.

Я уверен, что могут, но вот примеры в голову не идут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) ... до и после полуночи...

2) И баста!